# Ajax request to read csv file content from third-party server

Tags: jquery, ajax, csv, jsonp

I want to read the content of a csv file whose URL is "http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=CVX&a=01&b=19&c=2001&d=01&e=19&f=2016&g=v&ignore=.csv" by using ajax. I fall down below errors:

If I tried with below, I will get CORS error

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=CVX&a=01&b=19&c=2001&d=01&e=19&f=2016&g=v&ignore=.csv',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "text/csv",
        contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8',               
        success: function (data)
        {
            console.log("success " + data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log("error " + data);
        }
    });
```

Since I could not change server side, so I change to use jsonp with below code, it return 200 and I could view data in response body, but I got error "'Dividends' is undefined", and it fall in error line, I could not get the response data. I do not understand why it will read the content, and it even output error 'Dividends' which is the second column in csv file.

```
       $.ajax({
            url: 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=CVX&a=01&b=19&c=2001&d=01&e=19&f=2016&g=v&ignore=.csv',
            type: 'GET',               
            dataType: "jsonp",                            
            success: function (data)
            {
                console.log("success " + data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error " + data);
            }
        });
```

As my researching, it seems my datatype is jsonp, and return datatype is csv, so Ajax fall in error with status success.

Could you share me how to get content from the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of jsonp or text/csv, use text

```
dataType : "text"
```

for example

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=CVX&a=01&b=19&c=2001&d=01&e=19&f=2016&g=v&ignore=.csv',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "text",
    contentType:'application/json;charset=utf-8',               
    success: function (data)
    {
        console.log("success " + data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log("error " + data);
    }
});
```